# How to manipulate the production database data format using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, flyway

The situation looks like this:

- the Spring production application uses a table with a varchar column (MySQL),
- I need to change the column to binary blob,
- and encrypt the existing data (using Java, not database).

The two known steps of this process are:

- I need to update the Entity, changing the annotations (from varchar to blob)
- I need to run the migration changing the column format (using SQL with Flyway)
- all this will be done when I stop the application, replace the application jar (to the new version with changes) and run it again.

The problem:

- I need to take the old data from the column when it is still a varchar, encrypt it with Java, and after migration store it again in the blob column. (The new data which will be entered after the changes is not a problem, it will be automatically encrypted; the problem is with the old data.)
- what approach should I use to deal with this update? What general steps would be correct?

This is more a general Spring question - how do you deal with the situation, when you need to change the structure existing on production and manipulate the old data to fit the new format?

For example in PHP I'm using a terminal script integrated with application and run in the application environment (with "artisan" command in Laravel); I can easily create a proper order of the actions: take the old data and remember it, change the database structure, manipulate the old data, and insert the data to new structure - it's all in one script and one transaction. I don't know how to do this in Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer - the Flyway Java-based migrations: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#java-based-migrations

> Java-based migrations are a great fit for all changes that can not easily be expressed using SQL. These would typically be things like BLOB & CLOB changes, Advanced bulk data changes (Recalculations, advanced format changes, …)

It looks like this:

```
package db.migration;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.spring.SpringJdbcMigration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

/**
 * Example of a Spring Jdbc migration.
 */
public class V1_2__Another_user implements SpringJdbcMigration {
    public void migrate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO test_user (name) VALUES ('Obelix')");
    }
}
```

Database manipulation can be interleaved here with Java code and data manipulation.

I suspect that Liquibase has similar functionality.